# Why does bcrypt compare method always returns false?

Tags: node.js, jwt, mern, bcrypt

I doing some maintenance for an old code, which was working fine, but now somehow the login method isn't working properly as it should, and this's because of the "bcrypt.compare" function that always returns "false" and I don't know why. Below is my code. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it.

```
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Validate request body
    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email and password are required' });
        return;
    }

    // Check for email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    const isValidPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (user && isValidPass) {
        res.json({
            _id: user.id,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
            token: generateToken(user._id, user.isAdmin)
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
    }
});
```

I've also attached the registration method if it's relevant by any mean, in case someone wanted to check on the hashing method used upon the password creation.

```
const createNewUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    // Extract data from the request body
    const {
        username,
        email,
        password
    } = req.body


    /* Start Validation */
    // Check for all the required fields
    if (
        !username
        || !email
        || !password
    ) {
        res.status(400);

        throw new Error('Please add all the required fields');
    }

    // Check if the username exists
    const usernameExists = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (usernameExists) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('This username is taken, please choose another username');
    }

    // check if the email exists
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (emailExists) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('This email already exists, login instead');
    }
    /* End Validation */



    // Hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);


    // create new user 
    const newUser = await User.create({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });


    if (newUser) {
        res.status(201).json({
            _id: newUser.id,
            username: newUser.username,
            email: newUser.email,
            token: generateToken(newUser._id, newUser.isAdmin)
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('Invalid user data');
    }
});
```

Comment: What are the values of `password` and `user.password` on the call to `const isValidPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);`?